# NullPointerException with a ticking entity Minecraft modding 1.8

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Hello fellow coders,

I am writing a mod for Minecraft in 1.8 and have come across a pesky `NullPointerException` with my throwable. In the code below, the `EntityThrowable` uses an outer class to get the results of what will happen when thrown and the `BlockPos` passed is from the `getBlockPos()` method. This position is passed to the outer class where it transformed into x, y and z coords. However, whenever I throw the throwable, it throws an exception for these coordinates.

The difference between this question and the question of what is a NullPointerException is that the return value of what I am getting from the `mov.getBlockPos()` (from a `MovingObjectPosition`) is unknown. The `MovingObjectPosition` assigns the coords of the BlockPos from a random class and the coder of the Throwable gets the results. I am using the results for the outer class. These results in the ints cause the game to crash from unknown coords. If you have any idea of how to get the end pos of the throwable, that would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

Throwable:

```
@Override
protected void onImpact(MovingObjectPosition mov) {
    LuckyPotionItems lpi = new LuckyPotionItems();
    EntityPlayer player = this.getThrower() instanceof EntityPlayer ? (EntityPlayer) this.getThrower() : null;
    if(!worldObj.isRemote)
    lpi.chooseUnluckyDrink(worldObj, player, mov.getBlockPos());
    this.setDead();
}
```

Outer Class:

```
public void chooseUnluckyDrink(World w, EntityPlayer p, BlockPos pos){
    Random r = w.rand;
    int number = r.nextInt(13);
    int x = pos.getX();
    int y = pos.getY();
    int z = pos.getZ();

    System.out.println("Unlucky Number = " + number);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the problem could be solved by checking if the `BlockPos` and the `EntityPlayer` are not null. If they aren't null, then run the method. If they are null, simply prevent the method from being ran.

```
@Override
protected void onImpact(MovingObjectPosition mov) {
    LuckyPotionItems lpi = new LuckyPotionItems();
    EntityPlayer player = this.getThrower() instanceof EntityPlayer ? (EntityPlayer) this.getThrower() : null;
    if(mov.getBlockPos() != null && player != null) {
        if(!worldObj.isRemote)
        lpi.chooseUnluckyDrink(worldObj, player, mov.getBlockPos());
        this.setDead();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the thrower will likely be an EntityPlayerMP or EntityPlayerSP (i don't have any entities that throw these throwables or throwable launcher), I doubt this will work but I will try.

Comment: @TechGamer27 I see, in that case, you also want to check if the `BlockPos` is null, I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Was going to answer this :-) Always check your nulls, don't trust anything. sometimes code will be supplied by another mod, who lazily just supplies a null because then it works, or it's run on the server/client side and stuff turns to null too. Upvote to @Flibio

Answer (score 0):

```
number = (number == null) ? "" : number; 
System.out.println("Unlucky Number = " + number);

int x = (pos.getX() == null ) ? 0 :  pos.getX();
```

you are getting a null value for the number which means  there is no output in `r.nextInt(13);` you need to fix that. Im using a conditional statement to check the value of number if its null then it will assign a value for number which can then be printed. try with my example this would help you.

Comment: No, it is not crashing on the Random part. The code crashes when it assigns the integers.

Comment: you need to look into getter methods of `blackPos ex: getX() and getY()`